# Irreducibility of polynomials and its quotient

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, irreducible-polynomials

I got a couple questions I'm trying to work out.

a) Show that $x^4+2$ is irreducible in $\mathbb F_5[x]$

2) Describe the quoteint $\mathbb F_5[x]/(x^4+2)$

3) Show that $f(x) = x^4+5x^2-3$ is irreducible in $\mathbb Q[x]$.

---

For a), do I just try to come up with quadratic factors and show some sort of a conclusion?

b), I know that it will be a field of $5^4$ elements assuming that result from a) is true. Is there any other properties that I should note?

c) I thought if I could show that $f(x)$ is irreducible in $\mathbb Z[x]$, then by Gauss' Lemma, I can say that it is irreducible in $\mathbb Q[x]$ since the function is monic. But not sure how to show the irreducibility in $\mathbb Z[x]$, besides just trying to brute force with quadratic factors.

Any help would e appreciated!

Comment: @Sam Isn't that only for the polynomials of degree 2 and 3? Degree 4 polynomial could have quadratic factors..

Comment: @Sam: Not necessary. The polynomial $x^{4} - 4$ is reducible but has no roots in $F_{5}$.

Comment: You are correct in that for (c), it suffices to show that $f(x)$ is reducible over $\mathbb{Z}[x]$. There is a neat trick for this, so here is a hint: what do you get when you reduce the coefficients of $f$ mod $5$?

Comment: @AlexWertheim that was my initial idea, that it is actually congruent to the polynomial in part a. But I wasn't sure how that relates to $\mathbb Q[x]$ from $\mathbb F_5[x]$. Also, I wasn't sure how to prove a...

Comment: @user282639: the point is that if the image of $f$ in $(\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z})[x]$ is irreducible, then $f$ must be irreducible over $\mathbb{Z}[x]$, or else the factorization of $f$ over $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ would descend (mod $5$) to a factorization over $(\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z})[x]$. Now you can use Gauss' lemma as you wanted. As for part (a), there are two approaches one could take. It is easy (but perhaps tedious) to compute the irreducible quadratics over $(\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z})[x]$, and then you could check that $x^{4}+2$ is not divisible by any of these using Euclidean division. (cont)

Comment: Alternatively, it's possible that you could just write $x^{4}+2 = (x^{2}+ax+b)(x^{2}+cx+d)$ for $a, b, c, d \in \mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z}$, obtain a linear system on $a, b, c, d$ by equating coefficients, and then deduce some contradiction thereof. But I haven't tried this method, so I'm reticent to advertise this as the way to go.

Comment: @AlexWertheim If I were to proceed with the second method, I must do so still using mod 5 right?

Comment: @user282639: yes, this is what is meant by $a, b, c, d \in \mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: @AlexWertheim cheers, managed to reach a contradiction there. But stil not sure why irreducibility of $f$ in $(\mathbb Z/5\mathbb Z)[x]$ implies irreducibility in $\mathbb Z[x]$..is this only for primes or just any integer?

Comment: @user282639, well, this approach only really makes sense for primes, since $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ is not a domain for $n$ composite, and so talking about irreducibility in $(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})[X]$ doesn't really make sense in that case. Suppose $p$ is prime, and for simplicity $f \in \mathbb{Z}[X]$ is monic. If $f = gh$ for nonconstant $g, h \in \mathbb{Z}[X]$, then reducing the coefficients of both sides mod $p$, we get a factorization of the image of $f$ in $(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})[X]$. Hence, if the image of $f$ is irreducible, then $f$ must be irreducible over $\mathbb{Z}$.